# What are the nationalities of the magic weapons?

Tags: nanoha

It's obvious that the magic weapons that Nanoha and the rest wield have different nationalities, as Rising Heart speaks English, but Hayate's Knight's weapons don't.

I am wondering: what are the nationalities of the weapons based on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official answer to the reason for speaking a different language. But, the language is tied into the magic system that the device uses.

There are:

- English for *Mid-Childa* devices
- German for the *Ancient-Belkan* devices
- Japanese for *[Unison](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Unison_Device)* devices

*Unison* devices are the devices that merge with their master to increase the combat capabilities, such as *[Reinforce](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Reinforce)* and *[Agito](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Agito)*. The devices that are up for the debate are the *Modern-Belkan* devices, such as *[Strada](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Strada) (Erio)* using German, while *[Mach Caliber](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Mach_Caliber) (Subaru)* uses English.

My personal opinion would be that *Modern-Belkan* devices capable of transforming form would use German (*Strada*), while others do not (*Mach Caliber*).